# Texto "transparente" em java

Tags: java, swing, textbox, jtextfield

**Eu queria fazer um texto parecido com esse:**

[image: Imagem]
Esse texto "transparente", quando  clicado ele desaparece  e se pode começar a escrever na caixa de diálogo... alguém sabe fazer isso em Java?

Me ajuda ai gente!

Comment: www.code.google.com/p/xswingx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui. O truque é você criar um [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) com outros dois componentes dentro: Um [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) com o texto de sugestão e uma imagem com o ícone. E então você usa o [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) para capturar as alterações do texto do `JTextField` para decidir se o `JLabel` deve ficar visível ou não.

Eis aqui o código:

---

**JImage.java**:

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class JImage extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public JImage() {
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
        Dimension d = new Dimension(image == null ? 0 : image.getWidth(), image == null ? 0 : image.getHeight());
        this.setPreferredSize(d);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) return;
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

---

**JSearchField.java**:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class JSearchField extends JTextField {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JLabel emptyTextLabel;
    private final JImage iconImage;

    public JSearchField() {
        this.emptyTextLabel = new JLabel();
        this.iconImage = new JImage();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(emptyTextLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(iconImage, BorderLayout.EAST);
        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                emptyTextLabel.setVisible(getText().isEmpty());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                emptyTextLabel.setVisible(getText().isEmpty());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                emptyTextLabel.setVisible(getText().isEmpty());
            }
        };
        this.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
    }

    public String getEmptyText() {
        return emptyTextLabel.getText();
    }

    public void setEmptyText(String emptyText) {
        emptyTextLabel.setText(emptyText);
    }

    public BufferedImage getIcon() {
        return iconImage.getImage();
    }

    public void setIcon(BufferedImage icon) {
        iconImage.setImage(icon);
    }

    // Você pode usar este método se precisar fazer alterações no JLabel.
    public JLabel getEmptyTextLabel() {
        return emptyTextLabel;
    }

    // Você pode usar este método se precisar fazer alterações no JImage.
    public JImage getEmptyTextImage() {
        return iconImage;
    }
}
```

---

E para testar isso, aqui vai uma classe que cria uma tela com um `JSearchField`:

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class Transparente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Executa tudo dentro da EDT.
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Transparente::run);
    }

    // No seu projeto, é melhor você substituir isso por algo que carregue o ícone
    // a partir de um arquivo local ou desenhe de dentro da aplicação, ao invés de baixar da internet.
    private static BufferedImage carregarIcone() {
        try {
            // Ícone criado por Jonathan Lamim e obtido a partir de http://www.iconesbr.net/down_ico/6231/search
            // Lembre-se de sempre certificar-se que a sua licença de uso de imagem é adequada caso vá usar imagens de terceiros.
            // No caso deste ícone específico, ver mais informações em http://www.iconesbr.net/sobre
            return ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.iconesbr.net/iconesbr/2008/08/6231/6231_16x16.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void run() {
        // Cria uma tela com uma panel principal dentro. Usa esta panel para definir
        // o tamanho mínimo e preferencial da janela.
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Teste JSearchField");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(350, 50);
        jf.add(jp);
        jp.setMinimumSize(d);
        jp.setPreferredSize(d);
        jf.pack();
        Dimension sd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf.setLocation((sd.width - jf.getWidth()) / 2, (sd.height - jf.getHeight()) / 2);

        // Vamos usar o posicionamento absoluto.
        jp.setLayout(null);

        // Cria o JSearchField e o acrescenta a panel principal.
        JSearchField text = new JSearchField();
        text.setEmptyText("Pesquise...");
        text.setIcon(carregarIcone());
        jp.add(text);
        text.setBounds(10, 10, 130, 20);

        // Exibe a tela.
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Eis o resultado:

[image: Telas com um JSearchField]

A tela de cima é como aparece quando o texto da `JSearchField` está vazio. A tela de baixo é como aparece depois de eu ter digitado "teste".

E por fim, note que eu estou baixando o ícone de http://www.iconesbr.net/iconesbr/2008/08/6231/6231_16x16.png. No seu caso você não deverá fazer o código baixá-lo da internet, e sim carregá-lo de algum arquivo local ou mesmo desenhá-lo dentro da aplicação.